# Minecraft BE keeps lagging to a stop on Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one

I'm currently playing Bedrock Edition on version **1.18.2** and it seems like no matter what settings I use to create a world (to include ensuring no resource or behavior packs are added), after about 15-20 minutes of playtime, the world begins to lag to a stop. I've also noticed that this effect lingers in the menu system after leaving the world.

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, clearing all data associated with the game, restarting the Xbox, not playing for a week at a time, and no matter what I do, I still end up with this lagging issue that forces me to quit the game and relaunch.

***Note**: If I press the Xbox button on my controller to open the menu, the game will stop lagging for a few moments.*

---

How do I get this lag to stop happening so I can play as normal again?

Comment: Do you have any other games that are currently running in the background? My understanding is that the XbOne will leave an application open/running in the background, which can use up your resources

Comment: @Ben wouldn't restarting the Xbox clear that out though?

Comment: Depends on your [power settings](https://support.xbox.com/en-AU/help/hardware-network/power/learn-about-power-modes) - "Instant On" mode doesn't turn it off, it simply puts it in a sleep mode, so that you can power on and resume your games/apps faster.

Comment: Is it only Minecraft that does this? or doe other games do it as well?

Comment: @Ben just Minecraft, and I'll have to check the power settings in the AM, though I thought those only apply to "turning off" or "shutting down" the Xbox, not issuing a restart command using the power menu.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking if the console is overheated or you are too low on space. Many uninstall a few other games for a while and check if that works.